# Could not cast value of type '__NSCFNumber' (0x1105dc3c0) to 'NSString' Swift 3

Tags: json, swift, casting, nsdictionary

This is my url response

```
{
"base": "EUR",
"date": "2017-05-16",
"rates": {
    "AUD": 1.492,
}}
```

And this is my code

```
Alamofire.request("http://api.fixer.io/latest").responseJSON { response in
        guard let JSON = response.result.value else{
            print("Error")
            return
        }
            print("JSON: \(JSON)")
        let dict = JSON as! NSDictionary
        let base : String = dict["base"] as! String
        print("Base:", base)
        let date : String = dict["date"] as! String
        print("Date:", date)
        let rateDict = dict["rates"] as! NSDictionary
        let aud : String = rateDict["AUD"] as! String
        print("AUD:", aud)
    }
```

In Line **let aud : String = rateDict["AUD"] as! String** there is error with message as mentioned above in title. What's happening here. Please anyone help me.

Comment: it is a Number and you try to force cast it to String, that is what is happening - as the error message clearly states by the way. Just look at the json and see that there are no "" around the 1.492

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a floating point not a string. cast is to float

```
let aud = rateDict["AUD"] as! Float
```

---

Edit: Avoid force casting, as that may crash your app if the data is not expected.
Using code below will prevent crashes

```
if let rateDict = dict["rates"] as? [String : Any] {
    if let aud = rateDict["AUD"] as? Float {
        print("\(aud)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually forced casting to `Float` causes a crash.

Comment: Only if the json structure is not as above. I'll update

Comment: No, it crashes always even if the value is a floating point number. You have to cast to `Double`. Your edited code will never print the `aud` rate.

Comment: @vadian please see the screenshot it's working : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bcdxb.png

Comment: Weird. I get an exception in a Playground and in a project.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert it in string like,

```
let aud : String = String(rateDict["AUD"])
```

OR

```
let aud : String = NSString(format: "%0.2f", rateDict["AUD"]) as String
```